# Where does the frame pointer point after set up?

Tags: assembly, stack, x86

Despite looking at textbooks trying to grasp this, I'm having trouble.

```
    0x08048b29 <func+0>: push   %ebp
    0x08048b2a <func+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp
    0x08048b2c <func+3>: push   %ebx
    ...
    0x08048b30 <phase_2+7>: lea    -0x28(%ebp),%eax
```

In the lea instruction, I understand that %eax gets the value at 0x28 before %ebp, but where is that exactly? Is it 0x8048b29 - 0x28 (0x28 before the beginning of the function) or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ebp register is typically used within a function to access any arguments passed to the function.  Before this function is called, any arguments not passed by register are pushed onto the stack.  At the start of this function, the calling function's base pointer is saved.

(1)    `0x08048b29 <func+0>: push   %ebp`

The new top of the stack is copied into ebp to serve as the base pointer in this function.

(2)    `0x08048b2a <func+1>: mov    %esp,%ebp`

Finally, ebx is saved, which was likely a variable passed to the function in a register.

(3)     `0x08048b2c <func+3>: push   %ebx`

After all of this function entry code, the ebp register is pointing into the middle of the stack.  Above it on the stack (toward the newest pushed items) is the ebx value that was pushed in #3 above.  Below it on the stack are the old ebp from the calling function (saved in #1 above) and MOST importantly... any arguments passed to this function via the stack (done before the function was called).

(4)     `lea    -0x28(%ebp),%eax`

The final instruction is referring to one of those arguments passed by the stack.  ebp ends up pointing into the stack, not at any of the functions code addresses.  This is pretty normal for ebp, it is most often used as a pointer into the stack.

Comment: And the reason they do this, is so that the arguments can always be referenced by the same offset of ebp.  You can't use esp for this purpose, because this function may need to use the stack pointer for temporary push/pop instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this from the context of *calling* that function. The code which does so looks something like:

```
caller+...: push argN
caller+...: ...
caller+...: push arg0
caller+...: call func
```

i.e. the arguments are put onto the stack in such order that, on entry to `func()`, the stack will have the following layout:

```
[esp+(N*4)] : argN
...         : arg(N-1)...arg2
[esp+4    ] : arg1
[esp      ] : <return address to caller()+...>
```

Then you perform the `push %ebp; mov %esp, %ebp` sequence, which *changes* `%esp` (by -4) so that your layout now is:

```
[ebp+4+(N*4)][esp+(N*4)] : argN
...                      : arg(N-1)...arg2
[ ebp+8     ][esp+8    ] : arg1
[ ebp+4     ][esp+4    ] : <return address to caller()+...>
[ ebp       ][esp      ] : <saved %ebp of caller>
```

The code then goes on to push a few more registers on the stack - since that grows downwards each time `%esp` is changed by -4. Ultimately (which you haven't shown in your disassembly but it'll be there) you'll have an instruction `subl $..., %esp`. Which is what allocates space for your local variables. The final stack layout is something like:

```
[ebp+4+(N*4)][         ] : argN
...                      : arg(N-1)...arg2
[ ebp+8     ][         ] : arg1
[ ebp+4     ][         ] : <return address to caller()+...>
[ ebp       ][         ] : <saved %ebp of caller>
[ ebp-4     ][         ] : <saved %ebx of caller>
[ ebp-8     ][         ] : ...
...                      : region for local variables
[ ebp-??    ][ esp     ] : end of stack for func()
```

Any address between `[esp ... ebp-4]` is within what's called the stack frame for your function, and it contains either a register saved on behalf of the caller (like `ebx` in the case of the disassembly shown by you) or local variables.

Hence, when in your code you see any access to `%ebp - XX` it's in the local variable space, if you see `%ebp + YY` it's within the space that contains the function arguments.